# Issues with OLS Regression - highly similar X and Intercept coefficients

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I'm estimating a linear OLS regression using some software, and I have three variables: Y (dependent), X1 (independent), and Intercept (a column of "1"s I manually created).  I created Intercept because this particular software doesn't have a function to add a constant term.

The coefficients of X and Intercept are almost perfectly inverse (i.e. Intercept-coefficient = 1.5 and X-coefficient = negative 1.51).  Both Y and X are columns of very small percentage changes (i.e. 0.0001).  I've tried adding some other independent variables, and quickly run into multicollinearity issues - not sure if that's simply because the variables are highly similar, though.

I'm not very experienced with stats, are the coefficients a dead giveaway from statistical issues with the regression?  Any advice is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If you add 2.0 to all Y values, the intercept should increase to 3.5 and the slope should not change. This is an easy test to make and will verify the regression procedure itself.

Comment: Thanks @JamesPhillips.  That worked perfectly!  I can see the regression is actually looks okay when I do that.